# Saving account balance data securely

Tags: database, security, encryption, hash

I'm developing an application which currently just works on a client with no data saved on a server. I want that to change but I've come to realize the data that needs to be saved is quite sensitive. As in bank account balances.

Is there a way to securely save data like this? I mean numeric data. I would need to use this data to calculate some other things too.

What is the normal approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to store this kind of data is to encrypt it using the user's password prior to uploading it to the server. That way, your sever has no access to the data, and can only send it back to the client to be decrypted. This means that no calculations can occur on the server; they all need to occur on the client.

Any scheme that allows your server to access the data directly means that anyone with access to the server (whether because they are authorized, or because they have broken in), will have access to the data. The best way to avoid this is to avoid ever having direct access to the data.

Given a goal of storing a handful of numbers, here is a way I would probably attack it to balance complexity and performance with good security.

- Make a "global prefix" for your app (like "net.robnapier.thisparticularapp").
- Generate a per-user "salt" of prefix + username
- Generate a master key from the salt and the user's password using PBKDF2.
- For each field you would like to encrypt, name the field.
- To get a per-field encryption key, apply HMAC(master, keyname) to generate a new 256-bit key.
- Use that key to encrypt the field with AES-256-CBC:

  - Choose a random 8-byte IV (initialization vector)
  - Encrypt with AES(fieldkey, IV, data)
  - Store as IV+Encrypted (So a total of 16 bytes to store 8 bytes of data)

To decrypt, you recreate the key using PBKDF2, reading the IV off of the start of the field, and then decrypting the rest.

There are better encryption modes than CBC, but it's ubiquitous, and is likely good enough for this application. The downside of CBC for this is that if someone modifies your data in the database, it maybe hard to detect that, and the user could get a bad result. There are several ways to fix that, but this scenario doesn't sound like data integrity would be the major concern. (If it is, look into HMAC+CBC or an "authenticated block-cipher mode" rather than CBC.)

Comment: This seems like a great idea. Have you ever used this approach? This application is actually a small experiment of mine but I'd like to use good security practices of course.

Comment: Yes, I've built systems like this (specifically messaging systems that were intended to provide end-to-end encryption while allowing intermediary storage). A good design can require some amount of careful thought and a reasonable understanding of how cryptography works. I'll update with a few practical guides for store a handful of numbers.

Comment: Please do. I have no experience whatsoever with cryptography and some guidance would do. Specifically what encryption should be used for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the data using symmetric key Cryptography (use AES) and save the cipher text to the disk. This helps if the server is compromised and the data is stolen. However, the data is available as plaintext to the server-side app, so anyone who has access to the server (definitely anyone with admin privileges on the server) could potentially see the data. So physical security of the server too is paramount.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch... this is tricky, You will have to encrypt this data in something like a AES-256 encryption. this of-course will include all the data fields that could prove a potential security risk to the user such as : Password, email, name and so on.

To input this data you will have to ensure an SSL transmission with a session security login to prevent the copy of cookies. This is just what I can think of the top of my head.

You will be better off getting some type of proven tested third party software.